# Get all data of users after grouping by

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have two tables "Users" "Bookings" and I merged two tables and groping by the booking and users count and get a new table which has the count of users who made a specific count of bookings ex:

[image]

so in the first column (62 users made 3 booking and the second columns 52 users made 4 bookings)

I want to get the data of users when I click on any line on the graph, means when I click on the first line on the graph I want to show the 62 users in a table, can I do this or not?

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without seeing your data - please describe your data model and post a data sample. Also, why are you using SQL tag? Does not seem relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a SQL solution, it would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select userid
from bookings
group by userid
having count(*) = 3;
```

This gives the list of user ids.  You can use `in`, `exists`, or `join` to get additional information about the users if that is what you really want.